# Casting an anonymous array initializer list

Tags: arrays, c++11, casting, initializer-list

I can successfully do a C cast of an initializer list for an array of char strings, but can't seem to get it to work with a C++ cast (static_cast):

```
int main()
{
   char x[] = "test 123";

   // This works fine:

   char **foo = (char *[]) { "a", x, "abc" };
   std::cout << "[0]: " << foo[0] << "    [1]: " << foo[1]
             << "    [2]: " << foo[2] << std::endl;

   // This will not compile ("expected primary-expression before '{' token"):

   //char **bar = static_cast<char *[]>( { "a", x, "abc" } );
   //std::cout << "[0]: " << bar[0] << "    [1]: " << bar[1]
   //          << "    [2]: " << bar[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to use a C++ cast here? If so, what's the correct syntax? If not, why not, and is the C cast letting me get away with something I shouldn't be doing?

Ultimately, the reason I'm asking this is that I am calling a function that has a char array pointer as a parameter, and I would like to use an anonymous array as the calling argument.

I'm using GCC 4.4.6.

Comment: It's from C99, *"A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a braced enclosed list of initializers is a **compound literal**. "*, it's not a braced initializer like in C++

Comment: If you want to use a braced initializer syntax anyway, change the signature of that function to accept `std::array<std::string, 3>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can successfully do a C cast of an initializer list for an array of char strings

No, you can't. You didn't use an initializer list nor a C cast at all. What you used was a compound literal. It is a C language feature that doesn't exist in C++. Some compilers do support them in C++ as a language extension.

I highly recommend you to use a compiler option that at least warns when you use non-standard features to avoid confusion like this.

> but can't seem to get it to work with a C++ cast

You cannot cast an initializer list expression. You will have to initialize a named array normally, then the pointer - although you hardly ever really need a separate pointer variable since the array implicitly decays to a pointer in most contexts anyway.

```
const char* arr[] = { "a", x, "abc" };
const char** foo = arr;
```

---

> the reason I'm asking this is that I am calling a function that has a char array pointer as a parameter, and I would like to use an anonymous array as the calling argument.

If you can modify the function, then there are ways to allow the call without a named array. You could accept an `std::initializer_list`, or a type that can be constructed from an initializer list such as an instance of `std::array`.

---

PS. Implicit conversion from string literal to `char*` is not allowed in C++ either - but allowed by some compilers as a language extension. Use `const char*` here.

Comment: I had run across this document https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html. I wasn't sure it applied, since in this case 'x' is not a literal (but maybe its value is copied as a literal into the compound literal?). Also, that document was a little unclear on whether this was actually a cast or not. It refers to the parenthesized expression as a cast, but also says the result is different from a cast. Your answer (and Piotr's) provides more clarity. The function I referred to is legacy, so I may not be able to change it.

Comment: @user3065699 For clarity: the components of a compound literal are not required to be literals. The document that you link shows an example with a non-literal value for a field as well.